# Query Runs fine in MS-Access but doesn't execute in .net through jet 4

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access

Can anyone please for the love of god tell me why this query would fire fine in ms access 97 but not through .net jet 4.0 driver ?

```
Update SkechersPricat, Map_Size Set SkechersPricat.Size=Map_Size.GeminiSize,   
SkechersPricat.ourScale=3, SkechersPricat.OurSizeCol=Map_Size.GeminiSequence Where
SkechersPricat.Gender=Map_Size.Gender AND SkechersPricat.size=Map_Size.[size] and 
SkechersPricat.Gender in ('G','B') and Map_Size.GeminiScaletype=3 and 
SkechersPricat.SkechersStyleNumber like '*L'
```

Edit
 Ps I copied the code as is from the .net retvalue I used which is just a string varaible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LIKE query on an Access database via C# always returns COUNT(\*) of 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016044/like-query-on-an-access-database-via-c-sharp-always-returns-count-of-0)

Comment: @GordThompson this is for vb.net if you looked at the tags

Comment: @DavidB It works the same way in VB.NET as C# as both are using the same .NET framework.

Comment: @AndrewMorton did indead appear to work but strange thing is my other quyers with the * was firing fine bit strange thats why i didnt spot this

Comment: @GordThompson Will you give a proper answer so I Can mark you up thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting tripped up by the difference in LIKE wildcard characters between queries run in Access itself and queries run from an external application.

When running a query from within Access itself you need to use the asterisk as the wildcard character: `LIKE '*L'`.

When running a query from an external application (like your VB.NET app) you need to use the percent sign as the wildcard character: `LIKE '%L'`.

Comment: Thanks buddy I go through to languages vb.net and c# two sometimes the small things trip us up

Comment: why though would it work for some queirys and not orthers and def no the  other query works fine with * as it does modify the data in other quers